# nth-child and boostrap not working

Tags: css, image, css-selectors

I have 3 columns and i want each one to have a different image inside them.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="image"></div></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="image"></div></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="image"></div></div>
</div>

}

.image{
background-color: black;
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 400px;
width: 557px;
border: 5pt solid white;
}
```

I don't think the nth-child css is set out right, but couldn't find much to help me online.

```
div.col-sm-4:nth-child(1).image {
background-image: url(../images/chestnutRice.jpg);
}
div.col-sm-4:nth-child(2).image {
background-image: url(../images/diaryOfMine.jpg);
}
div..col-sm-4:nth-child(3).image {
background-image: url(../images/travelTheWorld.jpg);
}
```

At the minute each column is just black. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: add space between nth-child()  .image

Comment: Same problem :(

Comment: add dot(.) before image:

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tcA4PCnhc6YUwTNlCJxk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks guys, not sure how i "up comment" your answers or whatever.

Comment: No need, is it fixed? :)

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

typo here:

```
div..col-sm-4
```

should be

```
div.col-sm-4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
.container-fluid div:nth-child(1) .image{}
.container-fluid div:nth-child(2) .image{}
.container-fluid div:nth-child(3) .image{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo after third div.

```
div..col-sm-4
```

And there must be a space after the (1)

```
div.col-sm-4:nth-child(1) .image{
background-image: url(../images/chestnutRice.jpg);
}
```